# verifying a file signature with openssl dgst

Tags: openssl

I am trying to verify a signature for a file:

```
openssl dgst -verify cert.pem -signature file.sha1 file.data
```

- all it says is "***unable to load key file***"

The certificate says:

```
openssl verify cert.pem 

cert.pem: /C=....
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

However, I specifically don't care about verifying the certificate, I want only to verify the signature for a given file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385320/verifying-a-file-signature-with-openssl-dgst